# TDD - Extract interface or make methods virtual

Tags: c#, tdd

Whenever I want to stub a method in an otherwise trivial class, I most often extract an interface.
Now if the constructor of that class is public and isn't too complex or dependent on complex types, it would have the same effect to just make the method in question virtual and inherit.
Is this preferable over extracting an interface? If so, why?

Edit:

```
class Parser
{
    public IDictionary<string, int> DoLengthyParseTask(Stream s)
    {
        // is slow even with using memory stream
    }
}
```

There are two ways: Either extract an interface or make the method virtual. I actually prefer interfaces, but that could lead to an explosion of `IParser` `Parser` tuples...

Comment: Extracting roles (NOT interfaces) is preferable. It makes your design more obvious and demarcation of responsibilities clear. - I'd recommend the 'subclass and override' trick only for legacy code (where you don't have the authority/confidence to make non-trivial modifications)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to consider what you are trying to accomplish outside of your unit testing. **Do not** let your tool dictate your design.

Dealing in interfaces can help decouple your code, but these should be natural points of separation in your code (e.g. business logic or data access). Making methods virtual makes sense if you are going to inherit and overwrite those methods.

In *your case*, I would attempt to test the **behavior** that uses `DoLengthyParseTask` and not the method directly. This will provide a more robust test suite as well. You need to carefully consider whether this method really needs to be [**public**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yzh058ae.aspx)(meaning it can and *should* be referenced outside its own assembly).

Comment: Added an example. Hopefully that isn't to general, but what makes me afraid of using interfaces is that in most cases I wouldn't use them besides stubbing.

Comment: @Sebastian this could be a sign that your tests are too granular.

Answer (score 4):

By programming to an interface you get benefits of ease of mocking/stubbing in unit testing and loosely coupled code (and as a result, much higher flexibility), literally **for free** (the only drawback is more *artifacts* to manage).

Interfaces and inheritance are two separate things and it's not a good idea to use them interchangeably, even though it's possible. By marking method `virtual` you're essentially telling others not only they're **free to change** (override) this method in their implementations, but that you actually **expect them to** (and are you?).

Such design comes with rather heavy consequences, so unless you explicitly need it - you shouldn't use it. Try sticking to programming to interface instead.

One of good object oriented design principles state that you should program to an interface (*design by contract*, [Liskov Substitution Principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Solid_%28object-oriented_design%29)) and prefer [composition over inheritance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composition_over_inheritance) (not only your classes should implement interfaces/abstract classes, but also consist of such implementations).

It's worth noticing that your `Parser` example makes perfect candidate to be hidden behind abstraction (be it interface or base class). From its consumer point of view it doesn't matter how the data is created - for now you might think it's XML stream only, but requirements tend to change (and/or grow), and you might soon find yourself implementing binary file parser, data stream mining parser and what-not-else. Do it properly now, save yourself time and trouble later.

Answer (score 4):

Interfaces just make a contract for you, basically a promise that your implementation will provide access to a specified set of contact points (methods, properties, etc), with no specification of behaviour. You are free to do whatever you want as long as you honor the promise.

A base class on the other hand, in addition of a contract, specifies at least some behaviour that is coded in the class (unless everything is abstract, but that is another story). Making a method virtual still enables you to call in the implementation of the base, and still provide your own code along with it.

This inheritance of behaviour is basically the reason why multiple inheritance is a no-no in modern OOP, and multiple interface implementation is relatively common.

That said, you need to weight whether you just want to extract a contract, or you want to extract some behaviour as well, and the answer should be obvious for a specific case.

As for the `IParser` / `Parser` pairs, first they are great for unit testing and for dependency injection, and second, they do not charge you for class creation, so feel free to create as many as you want.